# Find htdocs path, no matter where file is stored

Tags: php

How can I find my htdocs directory.

When I execute the following command:

```
echo  dirname(__FILE__);
```

I get the following output:

```
/var/www/myexample.com/htdocs/required/css
```

I want to find path till /htdocs, but I don't want to hard-code the things

I know I can use:

```
dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))
```

But, that will work if the current file is in "css" directory. If I will move to some other directory inside "css" directory, then it will not work.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running Apache, the

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

environment variable should give you the current document root. See [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in the manual.

Comment: I was going to say this, until I checked my windows server and found that it wasnt set.

Comment: @BugFinder Interesting. Which server, Apache or IIS?

Comment: It is IIS, but, Im sure I've seen this in IIS before, maybe it was an older version of PHP - but it was installed with the windows installer, rather than by zipfile, so where as DOCUMENT_ROOT was exactly what I was thinking, my server said no!

Comment: @BugFinder I *think* in IIS, PHP relies on the `document_root` setting defined in php.ini. I can be wrong though

Comment: Possibly, but I can see running into issues if its more than one site on the server, or even virtual folders.

Comment: @BugFinder In Apache, `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will reliably map to the current `VirtualHost` document root, at least I've never seen an instance when it didn't. I don't know how multiple hosts are handled in IIS

Comment: I know it will in apache, Im talking in ISS, if you set it in php.ini I can see issues within the IIS structure

Comment: @Bug yeah. I don't know how that is solved there, I haven't done much work on IIS

Answer (score 2):

On most setups `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to find them all should $_SERVER['document_root'] be unavailable, including htdocs.

```
<?php
$scriptRelativeName = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], strripos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));  //get relative name of script case sensitive from script_filename provided by filesystem by getting position of script_name in url and substracting the filesystem path
$scriptRelativePath = substr($scriptRelativeName , 0, strrpos($scriptRelativeName, "/"));  //get relative path by subtracting everything after the last slash in the relative name
$rootFolder = str_ireplace($scriptRelativeName, "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);  //subtract the scriptrelativename from script_filename to get the root folder
echo "Relative Script Name: " . $scriptRelativeName . "<br>";
echo "Relative Script Path: " . $scriptRelativePath . "<br>";
echo "Htdocs/Root Folder Path: " . $rootFolder . "<br>";
?>
```